# custom matcher makes jasmine to hang

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Trying to call this custom matcher in jasmine testing tool but I got this error:

```
TypeError: matcherCompare is undefined
var result = matcherCompare.apply(null, args);
jasmine.js (line 1192)
```

My matcher:

```
/*
 * Extends jasmine expectations by defining new matchers
 */
beforeEach(function () {
   jasmine.addMatchers({
      toEqualArray: function(){
         var s = typeof this.actual,
             result = false; 
         if (s === 'object'){
            if (this.actual){
               if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this.actual) === Object.prototype.toString.call([])) { //'[object Array]'
                  result = true;
               }
            }
         }
         this.message = function(){
            if (result){
               return "Is Array";
            }
            return "Is not an Array";
         };
         return result;
      }
   });
});
```

The core of the code inside `toEqualArray` is already tested as a simple js function and is ok. My matcher doesn't have an argument as you can see. I use jasmine 2.0 standalone for my tests and my matcher resides in an external js file like in the example at the standalone version of jasmine. I even moved my matcher inside my specs replacing `jasmine` with `this` but with no result!
What am I doing wrong?

Jasmine hangs when I put in my spec this specific command:

```
expect(o.get('any')).toEqualArray();
```

where `o` is my object that returns (I tested and it's ok) an array!

I have to debug jasmine now :(

Comment: Searching for matchers I found these links: 1) https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery, 2) https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon,
3) https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture and 4) https://github.com/jeffwatkins/jasmine-dom. Any idea which is best for js&ajax tests based on jquery+custom code?

Answer (score 1):

For jasmine 2.0, the syntax for custom matchers was changed. Updated documentation is here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html