# How to rewrite Jasmine 2.0 custom matcher to use with Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

[AngularJS tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) has custom matcher that is not working in Jasmine [starting from version 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855087/custom-matcher-makes-jasmine-to-hang):

```
beforeEach(function(){
    this.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function(expected) {
        return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
      }
    });
  });
```

The attempt to modify matcher fails with error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'matcherCompare.apply')`

My matcher definition:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function(util, customEqualityTesters, actual, expected) {
        return angular.equals(actual, expected);
      }
    });
  });
```

[Jasmine 2.0 custom matcher docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html).

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function () {
        return {
          compare: function (actual, expected) {
            return {pass: angular.equals(actual, expected)};
          }
        };
      }
    });
  });
```